# MonoMac Console Application Returns Only First Character of nvarchar(max)

Tags: c#, sql-server, mono, monomac

I have a console application that I run on Mac OS X through Mono. Although it executes correctly on Windows OS, it only returns the first character of an nvarchar(max) variable. Here is the C# code:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(Variables.connectionString());
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("IndexPageDetailsGet", myConnection);

myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter parameterIndexPageID = new SqlParameter("@IndexPageID", SqlDbType.Int);
parameterIndexPageID.Value = indexPageID;
myCommand.Parameters.Add(parameterIndexPageID);

SqlParameter parameterIndexPageText = new SqlParameter("@IndexPageText", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);
parameterIndexPageText.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
myCommand.Parameters.Add(parameterIndexPageText);

myConnection.Open();
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
myConnection.Close();

return (string)parameterIndexPageText.Value; // Only returns the first character
```

And here is the Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IndexPageDetailsGet]
(
    @IndexPageID int,
    @IndexPageText nvarchar(max) OUTPUT
)
AS SELECT
    @IndexPageText = IndexPageText
FROM
    IndexPages
WHERE
    IndexPageID = @IndexPageID
```

Has anyone else witnessed this behavior and/or know how to work around it?

EDIT: Here is my Mono Version Information:

MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2
Runtime:
  Mono 2.10.9 (tarball)
  GTK 2.24.10
  GTK# (2.12.0.0)
  Package version: 210090011

Comment: Code seems fine - just a wild guess - have you tried setting the max size of the parameter to `Int.MaxValue` (instead of -1) ? Something like `new SqlParameter("@IndexPageText", SqlDbType.NVarChar, Int.MaxValue);`

Comment: Thank you. I tried your suggestion but got an exception:

Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 6 ("@IndexPageText"): Data type 0xE7 has an invalid data length or metadata length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to this. Instead of using a stored procedure that returns a string, I used one that returns a SqlDataReader. It then allows me a string with the full nvarchar(max) value. Hence, in C#:

```
string indexPageText = string.Empty;

SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(Variables.connectionString());
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("IndexPagesGetByIndexPageID", myConnection);

myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter parameterIndexPageID = new SqlParameter("@IndexPageID", SqlDbType.Int);
parameterIndexPageID.Value = indexPageID;
myCommand.Parameters.Add(parameterIndexPageID);

myConnection.Open();
SqlDataReader result = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

while (result.Read())
{
    indexPageText = (string)result["IndexPageText"];
    break;
}
result.Close();

indexPageDetails.indexPageText = indexPageText;
```

And the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE
    [dbo].[IndexPagesGetByIndexPageID]
(
    @IndexPageID int
)
AS SELECT
    *
FROM
    IndexPages
WHERE
    IndexPageID = @IndexPageID
```